# Docker Registry Mirror Is Not Working Anymore, Error "Manifest Unknown"

Tags: docker, registry, mirror

I have notice that my /mnt/user/appdata/registry/ folder is not increasing in size anymore. So I took a look and found that the DockerRegistry mirror is having some kind of problem getting the manifest from docker hub.

I'm running on unraid and using the latest DockerRegistry

```
docker run
  -d
  --name='DockerRegistry'
  --net='bridge'
  -e TZ="Europe/Budapest"
  -e HOST_OS="Unraid"
  -e HOST_HOSTNAME="Pac-Man-2"
  -e HOST_CONTAINERNAME="DockerRegistry"
  -l net.unraid.docker.managed=dockerman
  -l net.unraid.docker.icon='https://github.com/juusujanar/unraid-templates/raw/master/img/DockerRegistry-logo.png'
  -p '5000:5000/tcp'
  -v '/mnt/user/appdata/registry':'/var/lib/registry':'rw' 'registry:2'
```

I delete everything and then start from a clean system and it has the same problem

here is the logs from the docker container:

docker logs -f DockerRegistry

```
192.168.47.141 - - [09/May/2023:11:37:42 +0000] "HEAD /v2/runpod/pytorch/manifests/latest HTTP/1.1" 404 96 "" "docker/23.0.5 go/go1.19.8 git-commit/94d3ad6 kernel/5.4.0-148-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Go-http-client/1.1)"
time="2023-05-09T11:37:42.687812344Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code="manifest unknown" err.detail="unknown tag=latest" err.message="manifest unknown" go.version=go1.16.15 http.request.host="192.168.47.100:5000" http.request.id=6bfb3a39-0a12-459a-824a-fdeedcf4608f http.request.method=HEAD http.request.remoteaddr="192.168.47.141:51660" http.request.uri="/v2/runpod/pytorch/manifests/latest" http.request.useragent="docker/23.0.5 go/go1.19.8 git-commit/94d3ad6 kernel/5.4.0-148-generic os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Go-http-client/1.1)" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=4.856565ms http.response.status=404 http.response.written=96 vars.name="runpod/pytorch" vars.reference=latest
```

using docker on the unraid system works. i can pull the images but the DockerRegistry can't. i have tried login or not. also tested with known public images.

```
Configuration
/mnt/user/appdata/registry This is where Registry will store it's data.
Port 5000 Default connection port
```

any idea where I am going wrong?